# Prove that space is Hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $$H_0^1(0,1)=\{f\in W^{1,2}(0,1):f(0)=0\}$$
and a norm $$\| f\|=\left (\int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x\right )^{1/2}$$

be given. I want to show that if a sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $(H_0^1(0,1),\|\cdot\|)$ converges to $u$ and furthermore $u\in W^{1,2}(0,1)$  then $u$ must be in $H_0^1(0,1)$. In other words, $H_0^1(0,1)$ is a closed subspace of $W^{1,2}(0,1)$.

I tried the following:

The mean value theorem for sobolev functions is analogue to the one in the space of continuous functions on compact intervalls
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Now we have by assumption that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\ge N$
$$\|f-f_n\|^2=\int_0^1((f-f_n)')^2\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1(f'-f_n')^2\mathrm{d}x<\epsilon$$

Now using the MVT for sobolev spaces I can obtain
$$|f(x)-f_n(x)|-|f(0)-f_n(0)|=\int_0^x (f'-f'_n)\mathrm{d}y<\epsilon$$

Now since, $f_n(0)=0$ and $|f(x)-f_n(x)|$ converges to zero (we assumed that $f$ would be in the sovolev space and therefore also converges by supremum norm), I can conclude that $f(0)=0$.

I have no idea if this is correct and appreciate any corrections/improvement.

Comment: I see a problem: why doesn't the sequence of zero functions "converge" to the constant function 1 in this situation? (Perhaps you meant to use the usual $H^1$ norm which also has a contribution from the $L^2$ norm of $f$ itself.)

Comment: @Ian Why does a sequence of zero functions have to converge to 1?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta  According to the way you defined $\|f\|$, if $\{f_n\} \subset H^0_1(0,1)$ then $\|f_n\| = \|f_n - 1\|$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. This is indeed very strange, we would also have that $\|f_n\|=\|f_n-a\|, a\in (0,1)$ We might have to change to equivalence classes or something.

Comment: The difference is that your norm is a norm on $H_0^1$ but only a seminorm on all of $W^{1,2}$. You might try the following: show first that $H_0^1$ is a closed subspace of $W^{1,2}$. Thus it is a Hilbert space. Then show that $\|f\| = \left( \int |f'|^2 \right)^{1/2}$ is an equivalent norm on $H_0^1$. It is thus a Hilbert space, but with a different inner product than that of $W^{1,2}$.

Comment: But this is exactly what I wanted to do, I need to use the norm $\|\cdot\|$ to show that $H_0^1$ is closed in $W^{1,2}$.

Comment: The problem is that $H^1_0$ isn't actually closed in $W^{1,2}$ because the associated norm is only a seminorm on $W^{1,2}$. But $H^1_0$ *itself* is still Hilbert with respect to that norm.

Comment: @Ian I understand and this makes sense, but I don't see why it is necessary for the proof to have a (full) norm. I think it suffices to have a seminorm on the larger space, because everything needed is just completeness and this property is not lost when only having a seminorm, is it?

Comment: Yes it is, because under a seminorm you have sequences that converge to multiple limits, some of which are outside $H^1_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline of what you can do. The details aren't difficult to fill in but would make this answer too long.

First, let $W = W^{1,2}(0,1)$ and let $H = H_0^1(0,1)$.  Define norms
$$ \|f\|_W = \left( \int_0^1 |f|^2  + |f'|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \quad \text{and} \quad 
\|f\|_H = \left( \int_0^1 |f'|^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}.$$
Functions in $W$ are (absolutely) continuous, so identify each function with its continuous representative. Then the fundamental theorem of calculus gives you 
$$ \tag{1}\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \le \sqrt{2}\|f\|_W$$
and all $f \in W$ and
$$ \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \le \|f\|_H$$
for all $f \in H$. Moreover, after integrating the second inequality you get
$$ \tag{2} \|f\|_W \le \sqrt 2 \|f\|_H$$ for all $f \in H$. I'm not sure if the constant $\sqrt 2$ is best--it's not important for the argument.

Let $\{f_n\} \subset H$ be a Cauchy sequence in the norm $\| \cdot\|_H$. Then $(2)$ tells you $\{f_n\}$ is also Cauchy in the norm $\|\cdot \|_W$. Since $W$ is complete there exists $f \in W$ with $\|f_n - f\|_W \to 0$.

Now refer back to $(1)$: since
$$ |f(0)| = |f_n(0) - f(0)| \le \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \sqrt{2} \|f_n - f\|_W \to 0$$ you get $f(0) = 0$ so that $f \in H$. In light of the obvious inequality $\|\cdot\|_H \le \|\cdot\|_W$ you have $\|f_n - f\|_H \to 0$ too, implying that $H$ is complete with respect to its norm.

Since the norm of $H$ is induced by the inner product 
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f'(x) g'(x) \, dx$$ you conclude $H$ is a Hilbert space.